# How to find the log files which are 2 days older, ZIP them and move them to Amazon S3

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in find /var/lib/tomcat7/logs -name 'testing.*.log' -and -ctime +2 -exec bzip2 -zv {} \;
do
aws s3 mv $f s3://ri-uat-bucket/testing/
done
```

Comment: Does ec2 have attached role to s3 ? What is the error you are getting kindly post and elaborate question

Comment: I am not getting any error. This script is converting log to zip but not moving it to s3

Comment: You need to state the exact problem or error. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
for f in `find /var/lib/tomcat7/logs -name 'testing.*.log' -ctime +2`
do
bzip2 -zv $f
aws s3 mv $f.bz2 s3://ri-uat-bucket/testing/
done
```

Comment: Glad I was of help.